# Choice filter to lookup its values from a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

Is it possible to make a `choice filter web part` look up it's values from a column of other list? I want it to take it's values directly from other list so that manually filling it's values is no more required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `List view filter webpart` instead of choice filter webpart. It will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: good advice man...